# WordPress - why is my filter hook not working?

Tags: wordpress, add-filter

This `get_customizer_fonts_options` filter currently exists in the parent theme that I'm using. I'm also using a child theme and need to change this list of fonts.

Is it as simple as copying this into my child theme's functions.php file and changing the list of fonts, or do I use `add_filter` and create my own function with the changes? Thanks for any insight. I'm stumped.

`get_customizer_fonts_options` filter that lives in the parent theme:

```
if ( ! function_exists('get_customizer_fonts_options' ) ) {
    // Generates array with options used with typography control so all font lists have the same choises.
    function get_customizer_fonts_options( $context = false, $default = false ) {
        if ( $default ) {
            $default = array( 'inherit' => esc_html__( 'Default font', 'coll_school' ) );
        } else {
            $default = array();
        }
        if ( $context == 'header' ) {
            $fonts =  $default + array(
                    'public_sans'   => 'Public Sans',
                    'amstelvar'     => 'Amstelvar',
                    'commissioner'  => 'Commissioner',
                    
                );
        } else {
            $fonts = $default + array(
                    'public_sans'  => 'Public Sans',
                    'amstelvar'    => 'Amstelvar',
                    'commissioner' => 'Commissioner',
                    
                );
        }

        
        return apply_filters('get_customizer_fonts_options', $fonts, $context );
    }
}
```

My `add_filter` code in my child theme functions.php file that is not working:

```
function hwp_control_font_list($fonts, $context) {
if ( $default ) {
            $default = array( 'inherit' => esc_html__( 'Default font', 'cpschool' ) );
        } else {
            $default = array();
        }
   if ( $context == 'header' ) {
            $fonts =  $default + array(
                    'quicksand'     => 'Quicksand',
                    'raleway'       => 'Raleway',
                    'russolo'       => 'Russolo',
                    'roboto'       => 'Roboto',
                    
                );
        } else {
            $fonts = $default + array(
                    'quicksand'    => 'Quicksand',
                    'raleway'      => 'Raleway',
                    'roboto'       => 'Roboto',
                    
                );
        }
}
add_filter('get_customizer_fonts_options','hwp_control_font_list', 2);
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem but noticed that your `hwp_control_font_list()` function is trying to use `$default` (`if ( $default ) { ... }`) and as far as I can see `$default` is not defined anywhere nor it's being passed to `hwp_control_font_list()`. You only have access to `$fonts` and `$context`.

Comment: To answer your question: yes, you can redeclare `get_customizer_fonts_options()` in your child theme's function.php and change it according to your needs or you can use the available filter hook to change it without having to copy it into the child theme. Either way should be fine.